# The impact of virtual on the use of member of class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, virtual, instantiation

I (vaguely) know that a template is not instantiated if it is **not** *used*. For example, the following code will compile fine even though `T::type` doesn't make sense when `T = int`.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    void f() { using type = typename T::type; }
};

A<int> a; //ok
```

It compiles because `f()` is not *used*, so it is not instantiated — thus the validity of`T::type` remains unchecked. It doesn't matter if some other *member* function `g()` calls `f()`.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    void f() { using type = typename T::type; }

    void g() { f(); } //Is f() still unused?
};

A<int> a; //ok
```

This also [compile fines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6eba04e3741d673). But here I realize the vagueness in my understanding of the definition of *"use"*. I ask:

- Is `f()` still unused? How exactly?

I can clearly see it being used inside `g()`. But then I thought since `g()` is not used, `f()` is not used either, from instantiation point of view.  That seems reasonable enough. so far.

However if I add `virtual` keyword to `g()`, it doesn't compile:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    void f() { using type = typename T::type; }

    virtual void g() { f(); } //Now f() is used? How exactly?
};

A<int> a; //error
```

It results in [compilation error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e20d079078a024e6) because now it attempts to instantiate `f()`.  I don't understand this behavior.

Could anybody explain this? Especially the impact of `virtual` keyword on the definition of "use" of member of class template.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `virtual` forces instantiation of the member function because it is now nigh-impossible to statically assess whether this function will be used or not. In practice, you are asking to create a v-table filled with pointers to functions... so the function need exist so we can take a pointer to it.

Comment: The struct template only gets instantiated when you use it. It is either the entire struct or nothing. It doesn't have anything to do with g or f.

Comment: @Sarien: it does, member functions of a template class are only instantiated if ODR-used.

Comment: @Sarien: That would be really stupid to instantiate all the members even if you don't use them. Fortunately, C++ is smart and instantiates *only* what you use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick look at 3.2 [basic.def.odr] yields:

> 3/ [...] A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure. [...]

And I also found at 14.7.1 [temp.inst]:

> 10/ An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. **It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.** (emphasis mine)

So... I would say it is likely that a `virtual` method will always be instantiated.

In pragmatic terms, I would expect a compiler to instantiate the virtual table of a template class when it instantiates the class; and thus immediately instantiate all `virtual` member functions of this class (so it can references those from the virtual table).