# What does it mean to "odr-use" something?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

This just came up in the context of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630138/the-impact-of-virtual-on-the-use-of-member-of-class-template?noredirect=1#comment29143561_19630138).

Apparently member functions in class templates are only instantiated if they are odr-used.
Could somebody explain what exactly that means. The [wikipedia article on One Definition Rule (ODR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) doesn't mention "*odr-use*".

However the standard defines it as

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
> is *odr-used* unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for
> appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue
> conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.

in [basic.def.odr].

Edit: Apparently this is the wrong part and the entire paragraph contains multiple definitions for different things. This might be the relevant one for class template member function:

> A non-overloaded function whose name appears as a
> potentially-evaluated expression or a member of a set of candidate
> functions, if selected by overload resolution when referred to from a
> potentially-evaluated expression, is odr-used, unless it is a pure
> virtual function and its name is not explicitly qualified.

I do however not understand, how this rule works across multiple compilation units? Are all member functions instantiated if I explicitly instantiate a class template?

Comment: Note that [basic.def.odr]/6 applies to member functions of class templates "There can be more than one definition [...]"

Comment: *"Are all member functions instantiated if I explicitly instantiate a class template?"* Yes, see [temp.explicit]/8+9

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's just an arbitrary definition, used by the standard to
specify when you must provide a definition for an entity (as
opposed to just a declaration).  The standard doesn't say just
"used", because this can be interpreted diversely depending on
context.  And some ODR-use doesn't really correspond to what one
would normally associate with "use"; for example, a virtual
function is always ODR-used unless it is pure, even if it isn't
actually called anywhere in the program.

The full definition is in [§3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr), second paragraph, although this
contains references to other sections to complete the
definition.

With regards to templates, ODR-used is only part of question;
the other part is instantiation.  In particular, §14.7 covers
when a template is instantiated.  But the two are related: while
the text in §14.7.1 (implicit instantiation) is fairly long, the
basic principle is that a template will only be instantiated if
it is used, and in this context, used means ODR-used.  Thus,
a member function of a class template will only be instantiated
if it is called, or if it is virtual and the class itself is
instantiated.  The standard itself counts on this in many
places: the `std::list<>::sort` uses `<` on the individual
elements, but you can instantiate a list over an element type
which doesn't support `<`, as long as you don't call `sort` on
it.

Comment: could ODR-use has overlap with "materialized temporaries" ?

Comment: @v.oddou, maybe on a vague conceptual level.

Answer (score 44):

In plain word, odr-used means something(variable or function) is used in a context where the definition of it must be present.

e.g.,

```
struct F {
   static const int g_x = 2;
};

int g_x_plus_1 = F::g_x + 1; // in this context, only the value of g_x is needed.
                             // so it's OK without the definition of g_x

vector<int>  vi;
vi.push_back( F::g_x );      // Error, this is odr-used, push_back(const int & t) expect
                             // a const lvalue, so it's definition must be present
```

Note, the above push_back passed in MSVC 2013. This behavior is not standard compliant - both gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.8.0 failed, with error message:
`undefined reference to F::g_x`

Comment: Is it possible to odr-use a static data member like `vi.push_back( F::g_x );` in c++?

Comment: But  a rvalue could also be passed to `const int&` ?Could the static const member be ragarded as rvalue?

Comment: +1 for the succinct opening sentence: "In plain word, odr-used means something(variable or function) is used in a context where the definition of it must be present."

Comment: I don't understand how you compile that code. Are they in the same TU ?. If they are, F::g_x has already been defined before `push_back`, of course it will pass. Isn't it ?

Comment: @bigxiao"_a rvalue could also be passed_" Yes and a temporary object is created by the compiler and the reference bound to that object. OTOH when passing a lvalue that means passing that object referred to by the evaluation of the lvalue: when you pass a lvalue you can expect the parameter in the function to refer to the correct object. The compiler will not create a temporary. If you want a temporary, make one with `operator+`.

Comment: @LewisChan Nope, here `static const int g_x = 2;` is a declaration but not a definition.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer I don't think so. [This](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5sd7b6) complains of a duplicate instantiation. I believe what you're referring to is [this case](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aTe1Kz) instead which is where the static member isn't defined but only declared. I think `const` integral members are allowed to be *defined* inline.

Comment: @Zoso You're mixing up two things. In both of your examples `foo` is declared in the class, but not defined. The reason why you are getting an error in your first example is listed in [\[class.static.data\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#static.data-4) `... The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (6.3) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.` You **are** allowed to define them inline but neither of your examples contain the `inline` specifier.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Ok, I'm a bit confused. So the **declaration** in [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) is being **initialized**? FWIK, initialization *implies* definition, no? Because that would imply that some storage has been allocated to the variable?

Comment: @Zoso [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186005/why-int-const-bbsm1a-not-considered-a-redefinition/64188764#64188764), I just quite recently answered a similar question actually

Comment: @NotAProgrammer That helps! Essentially my doubt was what on earth happens with the value of the initializer if it's a declaration and not a definition. Your answer clears that it's stowed away in the [register](https://godbolt.org/z/7TPeb4) whereas it is actually allocated memory [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1zEfaY) on **definition**.

Comment: Since the relevant rule does not require a diagnostic, MSVC is conforming even if it accepts that code.