# When is a variable odr-used in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

The C++14 draft (N3936) states in §3.2/3:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

This doesn't make any sense to me: If an expression `e` is a *discarded-value expression* depends on the context, in which `e` is used. Every expression used in an *expression-statement* (§6.2) is a *discarded-value expression*. If the *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* is applied to `e` also depends on the context `e` is used in.

Moreover, what does it mean for an expression to be in the set of *potential results* of another expression. One needs a notion of equality of expressions to be able to determine membership of a set. But we don't have *referential transparency*, so I cannot see how this could be achieved.

Why was this changed from C++11 to C++14? And how should this be interpreted? As it stands, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 27):

### The purpose of odr-use

Informally, *odr-use* of a variable means the following:

> If any expression anywhere in the program takes the address of or binds a reference directly to an object, this object must be defined.

### Clarification in the latest draft

In the latest version of the spec §3.2 has been clarified (see [Draft C++14 on GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/aaaf8ae73d38389d25becc4a97f88f26a76457c1)):

> 2 An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. The set of potential results of an expression `e` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `e` is an id-expression (5.1.1), the set contains only `e`.
> - If `e` is a class member access expression (5.2.5), the set contains the potential results of the object expression.
> - If `e` is a pointer-to-member expression (5.5) whose second operand is a constant expression, the set contains the potential results of the object expression.
> - If `e` has the form (e1), the set contains the potential results of e1.
> - If `e` is a glvalue conditional expression (5.16), the set is the union of the sets of potential results of the second and third operands.
> - If `e` is a comma expression (5.18), the set contains the potential results of the right operand.
> - Otherwise, the set is empty.
>
> [ Note: This set is a (possibly-empty) set of id-expressions, each of which is either `e` or a subexpression of `e`.
>
> [ Example: In the following example, the set of potential results of the initializer of `n` contains the first `S::x` subexpression, but not the second `S::x` subexpression.
>
> ```
> struct S { static const int x = 0; };
> const int &f(const int &r);
> int n = b ? (1, S::x) // S::x is not odr-used here
>           : f(S::x);  // S::x is odr-used here, so
>                       // a definition is required
> ```
>
> —end example ] —end note ]
>
> 3 A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used **by `ex`** unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any nontrivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

### What was the situation in C++11?

§3.2/2 in C++11 reads:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is **immediately** applied.

The problem with these wordings was [DR 712](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#712). Consider this example:

```
struct S {
  static const int a = 1;
  static const int b = 2;
};
int f(bool x) {
  return x ? S::a : S::b;
}
```

Since `S::a` and `S::b` are lvalues the conditional expression `x ? S::a : S::b` is also an lvalue. This means that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is **not immediately** applied to `S::a` and `S::b`, but to the result of the conditional expression. This means that by the wording of C++11, these static data members are odr-used and a definition is required. But actually only the values are used, hence it is not neccessary to define the static data members - a declaration would suffices. The new wording of draft C++14 solves this.

### Does the new wording resolve all issues?

No. In the following example the variable `S::a` is still odr-used:

```
struct S { static constexpr int a[2] = {0, 1}; };
void f() {
    auto x = S::a[0];
}
```

Hence I submitted a new [issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1926) to add the following bullet to §3.2/2:

> - if `e` is a glvalue subscripting expression (5.2.1) of the form `E1[E2]`, the set contains the potential results of `E1`.

Comment: Good, but we need the potential results of both sides (`E2` as well as `E1`) to allow for reversed subscripting (`0[S::a]`).

Comment: Also, if subscripting is allowed then indirection should be as well (`*S::a`).  There's an interesting parallel to 5p11 here.

Comment: @ecatmur I agree about reversed subscription. Thinking about indirection, I'm not so sure if the submitted issue can be realized. Since subscription is identical to indirection, we always have the array-to-pointer standard conversion. This means that somehow that we must be able to take the adress of the variable, what implies odr-use.

Comment: We can sidestep array-to-pointer conversion if the integral side is a constant expression with value respecting the array bound of the other side; I think this should be in the 3.2p2 bullet.  All that's left then is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and we just need to adjust 3.2p3 to apply that to the element type of the array rather than the array itself.

Comment: Suggested wording: https://gist.github.com/ecatmur/cf7bc1e0e79ee6fe408e#file-gistfile1-md

Comment: That informal definition of odr-use is good for objects, but "odr-use" also applies to functions.  (And informally, a function is odr-used if it might be called.)

Comment: @aschepler I'm only talking about variables. Fixed first sentence.