# Static constexpr odr-used or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, one-definition-rule

How come that the following works on `gcc` but doesn't on `clang`, (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc1887da0ea50cfe)*):

```
constexpr int giveMeValue() { return 42; }

struct TryMe {
  static constexpr int arr[1] = {
      giveMeValue()
  };  
};

int main() {
    int val = TryMe::arr[0];
    return val;
}
```

I get an unresolved external symbol with clang.

Is `TryMe::arr[0]` an object? If it is, is it odr-used?

Comment: Which version of clang?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b319b9351784244 Did you turn on `C++11 flag`?

Comment: uhm.. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc1887da0ea50cfe

Comment: Duplicate: [Is a constexpr array necessarily odr-used when subscripted?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23428684)

Comment: @dyp according to that post then gcc is wrong, did I get that correct? Is it a bug?

Comment: @MarcoA. odr-violations are not required to be diagnosed.. so you could only ask the g++ developers nicely to add a diagnostic that it's an extension (or UB) ;)

Comment: @dyp I don't think it is a duplicate of that question at least, since the main question here is why are the results inconsistent. Although closely related they are not the same.

Comment: @texasbruce: Your implementation works because you added a definition `constexpr int TryMe::arr[1];` outside `struct TryMe` which makes it so there is no odr violation. OP's code lacks such a definition.

Comment: Why don't we want to answer questions in comments? Questions without answers are more likely to be automatically removed via [roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/213111) and comments are second class and even useful comments can be removed at times.

Comment: @AndyG You mean the declaration (not definition)? You can safely remove that line and it will still work.

Comment: @texasbruce: Hmm, perhaps the compiler is optimizing away the vbl declaration because it's unused. If you try to return `val` out of `main()` you will get the error.

Comment: I updated my answer, due to defect report 1926 your code should be well formed in C++1z and I think C++14 as well.

Answer (score 9):

`TryMe::arr` is [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) but you don't provide a definition (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66938aea39feee23)*):

```
constexpr int TryMe::arr[1];
```

Why is the result inconsistent between `gcc` and `clang`? This is because odr violations do not require a disagnostic, from both the C++11 and C++14 draft standard (*emphasis mine*):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; **no diagnostic
>   required**.

We can see it is odr-used from the draft C++11 standard, section `3.2` which says:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated
>   operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name
>   appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is
>   an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant
>   expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is
>   immediately applied.

`TryMe::arr` is an object and it does satisfy the requirements for appearing in a constant expression but the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not immediately applied to `TryMe::arr` but to `TryMe::arr[0]`.

The updated wording from the draft C++14 standard which applies to C++11 as well since it was applied via a defect report(*[DR 712](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#712)*):

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1)
>   to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any
>   non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the
>   set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression

The *potential results* of the expression `TryMe::arr[0]` is empty by the criteria in `3.2` paragraph `2` and so it is odr-used.

Note: you need to provide a definition outside of the class as per section `9.4.2` *[class.static.data]* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class
>   definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall
>   specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause
>   that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In
>   both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end
>   note ] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it
>   is odr-used (3.2)** in the program and the namespace scope definition
>   shall not contain an initializer

**Update**

T.C. pointed out [defect report 1926](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1926) which adds the following bullet to `3.2` [basic.def.odr] paragraph 2:

> - If e is a subscripting operation (5.2.1 [expr.sub]) with an array operand, the set contains that operand.

Which means subscripting an array is no longer an odr-use and so the OPs code would be well-formed in C++1z and it seems like C++14 since the defect looks like it is against C++14.

Comment: Some more clarification about declaration vs definition. What OP has in his `TryMe` struct may appear to be a definition, but in fact is a declaration because of the funny rules about when a declaration is also a definition. Here OP has a `static` variable with an in-class member initializer, which is usually disallowed, but is allowed here because of `constexpr` (and `int`). However, OP hasn't actually allocated memory for `TryMe::arr` because the variable is also `static` which requires external storage. So, like any `static` variable, OP still must provide a declaration outside the struct.

Comment: (Continuing previous comment because I ran out of room). However, it's not a good idea to provide the definition `constexpr int TryMe::arr[1];` in the same file that OP defines the `TryMe` struct because any class that wants to include the definition for struct `TryMe` will then attempt to allocate storage for `TryMe::arr[1]`, violating the One Definition Rule. So what usually happens instead is that you would put the `constexpr int TryMe::arr[1]` in a .cpp file of some sort, separate from the header.

Comment: @AndyG fair point, I assumed some knowledge, I should have added more detailed. Let me add more details.

Comment: I thought your post was great! I just wanted to add some extra detail for those lurkers who happened upon it, so it wasn't a jab at you.

Comment: @AndyG no worries, I always welcome constructive comments. You pointed out important details that I did not think to point out.

Comment: @T.C. I knew that was in the latest draft but I did not realize it came in via a DR, let me update.