# How to use make_tuple() in static constexpr class member?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to use `make_tuple()` in `constexpr`. It works in global scope. But it generates link error for `static constexpr` class member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    static constexpr auto z = make_tuple(5, 3.0);
};

constexpr auto tp = make_tuple(6, 3.2);

int main()
{

    cout << get<0>(tp) << " " << get<1>(tp) << endl; // OK

    cout << get<0>(A::z) << "  " << get<1>(A::z) << endl; // error: (.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `A::z'
                                                          //        (.text+0x67): undefined reference to `A::z'

}
```

I have checked [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) `make_tuple` is not itself a `constexpr` in `c++11`. I guess that is not the problem in this case. If it was it would generate a compile error instead of link error.

I have tried to define the `constexpr` outside the class like bellow as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930465/1992776)

```
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr tuple<int, double> z;
};

constexpr tuple<int, double> A::z = make_tuple(5, 3.0);
```

But, it generates several compile error. That makes sanse according to answers of [constexpr initializing static member using static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522399/constexpr-initializing-static-member-using-static-function)

What is the correct way to use `make_tuple` in `static constexpr` class member?

Compiler:
`g++ 4.8.4` and `clang 3.4` with `-std=c++11`

Comment: [works well for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc0d0fef61b17c97).

Comment: not with a non-intrinsic object sadly. Use a static constexpr function to deliver the object.

Comment: what is the g++ version of this compiler?

Comment: wait.. this works in latest version of gcc and clang.

Comment: @user0042 This is an ODR issue. [Turn off `-O2` and it will no longer work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6661ed843ce519a)

Comment: It [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/457d588215a47446) on GCC 4.8

Comment: @BiagioFesta to be specific my `g++ --version` output is `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`. It does not work with it.

Comment: @army007 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e8f881f5aa37d10

Comment: @user0042 can you please elaborate on the ODR issue. Why it does not work with -O2?

Comment: _@army007_ Sounds like it's rather a job for @cpplearner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11/14, `static constexpr` variables must be *defined* somewhere if ODR-used (ODR-used means "used in a way that requires it have an identity".  As an example, take a real reference or pointer to them.  ODR here means "one definition rule", and ODR-used means "used in a sense that requires it to have exactly one definition", which I shorten to "have an identity").

[Simply add:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1325a5058f5bf93)

```
constexpr tuple<int, double> A::z;
```

and we have defined where it exists.  This needs to be in exactly one compilation unit.

In C++17, `inline` variables were added and I believe `constexpr` variables were implicitly made inline.  I'm not a C++17 expert, but [it compiles and runs in C++1z mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f553a824fff12233) without the definition, so my interpretation seems at least half correct.

(`inline` variables, like `inline` functions, have the definition in the end created wherever the compiler wants.  `inline` functions are typically implemented by having a definition in every object file with special notes when someone takes an address of it, then the duplicates are discarded at link time and everyone refers to the last one standing.  I don't know if `inline` variables tend to be implemented the same way or not.)

If you want to solve this problem in C++11 without having to put something in a `.cpp` file with hardcoded template arguments, [change `z` to a `constexpr` function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec83f0b90e680cca) and call it when you want to use it.

---

As SergyA has mentioned, ODR is triggered here because `get` returns a *reference* to a field in the tuple in question, and that reference implies an identity must exist for the field and hence the entire tuple.

In theory, a carefully crafted `value_get` that returned by value could avoid this ODR-usage, but it would depend on the implemenation of `tuple` as it in turn could not call `get`.

Comment: I would just add that the ODR-usage here happens due to the fact that get<> returns a reference. I imagine, it should be possible to do my_get<> returning value, which would not trigger the problem.

Comment: *defined*, not declared. The implicit inline applies to static data members only.

Comment: @yakk Thanks for explaining how it violated ODR and suggestion to make it `constexpr` function.