# Undefined reference error when initializing unique_ptr with a static const

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

When I try to use a `static const` to initialize a `unique_ptr`, I get an "undefined reference" error. However, when I `new` a pointer using the same constant, the symbol seems to be magically defined.

Here is a simple program that reproduces the error:

**Outside_library.h**

```
class Outside_library
{
public:
  static const int my_const = 100;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Outside_library.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class My_class
{
public:
  My_class(int num)
  {
    m_num = num;
  };

  virtual ~My_class(){};

private:
  int m_num;
};

int main(int, char* [])
{
  My_class* p_class = new My_class(Outside_library::my_const);
  delete p_class;

  // ==== ERROR HERE: When I comment this line out, the program runs fine.
  std::unique_ptr<My_class> p_unique
      = std::make_unique<My_class>(Outside_library::my_const);

  std::cout << "I made it through!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the program using

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++14
```

and got the following error.

```
/tmp/ccpJSQJS.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `Outside_library::my_const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone please help me understand why the constant is defined when using `new`, but not when using `make_unique`?

Comment: @RickAstley: Decrease optimization level: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b33a3d123f16ee10)

Comment: @Jarod42 Good one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has something known as the [One-Definition Rule (ODR)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition):

> Informally, an object is odr-used if its value is read (unless it is a compile time constant) or written, its address is taken, or a reference is bound to it; a reference is odr-used if it is used and its referent is not known at compile time; and a function is odr-used if a function call to it is made or its address is taken. If an object, a reference or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is usually a link-time error.

The linked site gives the following example:

```
struct S {
    static const int x = 0; // static data member
    // a definition outside of class is required if it is odr-used
};
const int& f(const int& r);

int n = b ? (1, S::x) // S::x is not odr-used here
          : f(S::x);  // S::x is odr-used here: a definition is required
```

Your explicit constructor invocation does not "odr-use" `Outside_library::my_const` but the call to `std::make_unique()` does. When an object is odr-used it must have exactly one *definition* (not *declaration*). Your example has a declaration only. Again from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition):

> 1. a variable x in a *potentially-evaluated* expression ex is odr-used unless both of the following are true:
>
>    - applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to x yields a constant expression that doesn't invoke non-trivial functions
>    - either x is not an object (that is, x is a reference) or, if x is an object, it is one of the *potential results* of a larger expression e, where that larger expression is either a discarded-value expression or has the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to it

The solution as suggested by Jarod42 is to use `constexpr` instead of `const` (if you have control over the "outside library" code). If you do not, then you'll need to link the program against the library that contains the *definition* of `Outside_library::my_const`.

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++14 -lOutside_library
```

Comment: Wonder if `constexpr` is enough, clang still has linker issue [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab8083f98deca80f)

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't know `constexpr`'s could be odr-used but I guess so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196095/static-constexpr-odr-used-or-not and gcc just doesn't diagnose it. Interesting.

Comment: And so, why does the new() call does not odr-use the static member? It looks like both the new() and std::make_unique are 'using' it?

Comment: @Nuclear: It is actually up to the compiler to decide whether to odr-use it through a link-time reference or just calculate the constant value, since semantically the value is defined and can be evaluated in all contexts. This is not defined by the C++ standard. Turning on optimizations will also usually make the problem go away. Or passing in a variable which you initialize with the constant instead of passing the constant. And the same happens with new. The move semantics of the make_unique<> seems to trigger the odr-use for non-optimized executables.

Answer (score 3):

`make_unique` takes (forwardind) reference of its parameter, and so odr-use it.

`My_class(Outside_library::my_const)` only use the value.

One solution is to define the member in a TU:

```
const int Outside_library::my_const;
```

<strike>or using `constexpr` value (since C++11):</strike>

```
class Outside_library
{
public:
    static constexpr int my_const = 100;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the code which declares the `static const int` the following usually works:

```
std::make_unique<My_class>(Outside_library::my_const + 0);
```

Adding `+ 0` usually forces the compiler to evaluate this as an expression before it is passed through the move reference of `make_unique<>`. This avoids generating a (completely useless and unnecessary) link-time reference to the constant "variable".