# Link error when using std::make_unique when creating object with const char *

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

Apologies for not providing simple runnable failure code. The error is part of the larger codebase that would require a lot of refactoring.

I'm running into a very weird linking problem with my code that so far I can't solve.
I have a class with `static constexpr const char *` for some strings and local `std::sunique_ptr`. The pointer is to a different templated class which contains another templated class (#2).

The main class is like this (abridged):

```
class Manager {
 public:
  Manager();

  virtual ~Manager();

 private:
  // Topic Constants
  static constexpr const char* kActuatorsCommand = "ActuatorsCommand";
  static constexpr const char* kActuatorsProxy = "ActuatorsProxy";

  std::unique_ptr<DataReader> faults_;
};
```

So the `DataReader` constractor takes two `const string &` parameters.

If I declare `faults_` as a regular old pointer and create it with `new` the code runs and links just fine: `DataReader *faults_ = new DataReader<uint32_t>(kActuatorsCommand, kActuatorsProxy)`.

However, if I use `std::make_unique` the linker complains that there is an undefined reference to those `static const char*` strings, even though they are in the header of the class.

Also, If I remove the #2 class everything links fine.

Using `gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`

---

I understand it may be rather vague question, but some direction where to look would be appreciated.

Also, this question may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428550/undefined-reference-error-when-initializing-unique-ptr-with-a-static-const). However, in my case everything is on one binary.

---

Update: finally found how to reproduce it.

```
class DataReader {
 public:

  explicit DataReader(const std::string& topic, const std::string& library_name)
      : topic_(topic),
        library_name_(library_name) {
  }

 private:
  const std::string name_;
  const std::string topic_;
  const std::string library_name_;
};


#include <memory>
#include "DataReader.h"

class Manager {
 public:
  Manager();
  virtual ~Manager();

 private:
  // Topic Constants
  static constexpr const char* kActuatorsCommand = "ActuatorsCommand";
  static constexpr const char* kActuatorsProxy = "ActuatorsProxy";

  std::unique_ptr<DataReader> faults_;
};


Manager::Manager() {
    faults_ = std::make_unique<DataReader>(kActuatorsCommand, kActuatorsProxy);
}

Manager::~Manager() {}
```

The code fails to link when compiled with `-o0`. With `-03` it links fine.

```
g++ -O0 -Wall -Wconversion -lstdc++ -pthread -std=c++14 -o ex3 src/ex3.cpp
/tmp/ccJebZ18.o: In function `Manager::Manager()':
ex3.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `Manager::kActuatorsProxy'
ex3.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `Manager::kActuatorsCommand'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'ex3' failed
```

Comment: It sounds like what you've described could just be made into a smaller [mcve]: you already have `Manager` with the `const char*`, and you've described `DataReader` as taking two `std::string& const` parameters, are you sure you can't just reproduce this with an extra few lines of code?

Comment: I tried. I didn't succeed yet. Something else is missing in my smaller example that is causing the large one to fail. The irony is - once I find it I will be able to fix the main problem.

Comment: I forget if `constexpr` changes things in this case so not dupe closing.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284629/undefined-reference-to-static-variable-c

Comment: The difference is `make_unique` takes its parameters by reference, which makes them odr-used; whereas `std::string` takes them by value. I suspect that either of these would work: `std::make_unique<DataReader>(kActuatorsCommand + 0, kActuatorsProxy + 0)` , `std::make_unique<DataReader>(std::string(kActuatorsCommand), std::string(kActuatorsProxy))` . The latter is essentially what happens when `DataReader` constructor is called directly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: indeed `std::string(kActuatorsCommand)` worked. I guess it creates the local copy of the static string and passes a reference to that to the constructor. Making the names just `static const char*` also worked. I just wonder why removing variable of class #2 from `DataReader` didn't fail linking.

Comment: I think it has something to do with inlining

`A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline`

When you compile the code with `-O3` or `-O0 -std=c++17` the static variable might be inlines which avoids the undefined reference. As to why you get an undefined reference in the first place I have no idea.

Comment: @MaLarsson: it links fine in C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with inlining

> A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable
>   (since C++17) declaration implies inline

When you compile the code with `-O3` or `-O0 -std=c++17` the static variable might be inlines which avoids the undefined reference.

I did some digging and found:

> You can take the address of a static member if (and only if) it has an
>   out-of-class definition

From [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#in-class).
Adding the following code to your example outside of the class body made it compile using `-std=c++14`:

```
constexpr const char* Manager::kActuatorsCommand;
constexpr const char* Manager::kActuatorsProxy;
```

Comment: Well worded, @MaLarson