# Passing constexpr member as a reference triggers linker error with gcc in debug or -O1 modes

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, constexpr

The code below triggers error with gcc 'undefined reference Foo::d' and 'undefined reference Foo::i'. Strangely, it happens only if I compile it in -Og, or -O1 optimization mode, but not with -O2 or -O3. Moreover, if I pass `constexpr double` as parameter for `int&` and vice versa (see last too calls) -- it does not trigger error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  static constexpr double d = 10.0;
  static constexpr int i = 10;
}; //class Foo

void print_double_ref(const double& v)
{
  printf("v = %g\n", v);
}

void print_int_ref(const int& n)
{
  printf("n = %i\n", n);
}

int main()
{
  Foo a;

  //This part triggers link error with -Og, -O1
  //No error with -O2, -O3
  print_double_ref(a.d);   
  print_int_ref(a.i);

  //This part does not trigger link error with -Og, -O1
  print_int_ref(a.d);
  print_double_ref(a.i);
}
```

I understand, that problem is somehow related to declaring argument of functions `print_double_ref` and `print_int_ref` as references. The questions are:

1. Why link error in -Og and -O1 modes only?
2. Why passing `constexpr double` as parameter for `const int&` (or `constexpr int` as parameter for `const double&` does not produce error?

Update: I know that for `static const` members one should initialize them outside the class. However, `constexpr` variables must be defined at the point of declaration. Why such a construct is allowed to be compiled then?

Comment: I think the proper syntax to avoid linker errors is `static inline ...`. See here: [static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Comment: This is related to the so called ODR-usage (to put it simple: taking address via pointer or reference) of a variable that is only declared, but not defined. Split definition and declaration or make the variable inline.
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member

Comment: Can't repro: https://godbolt.org/z/jfd6177sa you should provide more detail about build process.

Comment: I now see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), that `static constexpr int i = 10;` should imply `inline` and is therefore a definition (not only a declaration). So there should be no linker error. That's from c++17. Which version of c++ do you use ?

Comment: @wohlstad the error appears in C++11 and C++14. For C++17 and C++20 it links ok.

Comment: @alagner `constexpr` must be defined at the point of declaration.

Comment: @one_two_three looks like in c++14 or earlier you are left with `const` instead of `constexpr`. It doesn't seem problematic in your case. Just use `const` and add a definition (or use c++17).

Comment: @one_two_three still the rule about static class member still applies, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28446388/4885321 Note: "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program does not contain definitions of `Foo::i` and `Foo::d` (only declarations) and these things are being [ODR-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use). The behaviour is thus undefined.

Passing to a wrong reference parameter type does not trigger binding a reference, but rather creation of a temporary, to which a reference is then bound. So no ODR-use in this case.

Comment: I understand it for `static const double`, but not for `static constexpr double` -- there is no way to split `constexpr` declaration and definition.

Comment: @one_two_three https://godbolt.org/z/6Yfox436c