# odr-use of forwarded constexpr argument?

Tags: c++, c++14

In the following...

```
struct C {};
constexpr C c;

void g(C);

template<typename T>
void f(T&& t) {
  g(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
  f(c);
}
```

Is `c` odr-used?  Why / why not?

Answer (score 4):

Going through the same motions as [in Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436665/596781), we find that the second condition for *not* being odr-used is violated, and thus `c` *is* odr-used. In detail, the condition reads:

> [A variable `x` is *odr-used* by an expression `ex` unless `x` is an object and] `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression.

In our case `x` from the Standard is your `c`, and `ex` is the id-expression `c`. The only expressions of which `ex` is a potential result is the id-expression `ex` itself. It is neither a discarded-value expression, nor is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to it (since it binds to a reference).

Comment: So what is the actual answer to the question that you link to? There are two answers (+12 and +1) for "yes it is odr-used" and one (+4) for "no it's not."

Comment: @Barry: That's why I linked to the answer, not the question :-)