# Static Constexpr in Struct not found

Tags: c++, struct, constexpr

I have the following simple struct, which represents an OpenGL texture:

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <string>

#include "Shader.hpp"

struct Texture
{
    static constexpr GLenum UNIT[] = {GL_TEXTURE0,  GL_TEXTURE1,  GL_TEXTURE2,  GL_TEXTURE3,
                                      GL_TEXTURE4,  GL_TEXTURE5,  GL_TEXTURE6,  GL_TEXTURE7,
                                      GL_TEXTURE8,  GL_TEXTURE9,  GL_TEXTURE10, GL_TEXTURE11,
                                      GL_TEXTURE12, GL_TEXTURE13, GL_TEXTURE14, GL_TEXTURE15};
    int width, height;
    int unit;
    GLuint id;

    void use(const Shader &shader, const std::string &name) const
    {
        glActiveTexture(UNIT[unit]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
        glUniform1i(shader.getLocation(name), unit);
    }
};
```

The variables `GL_TEXTURE0` through `GL_TEXTURE15` are defined in glew.h, as per this excerpt:

```
#define GL_TEXTURE0 0x84C0
#define GL_TEXTURE1 0x84C1
#define GL_TEXTURE2 0x84C2
//etc...
```

When I try to compile my code I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Texture::UNIT", referenced from:
      Texture::use(Shader const&, std::__1::basic_string<char,     std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I obviously defined and initialized `UNIT` in the struct, yet it claims it doesn't exist. This error persists if I change `UNIT` to `Texture::UNIT` when it is accessed in the `use` method. It also persists if I change the type of `UNIT` to an array of integers. Why is this error being generated?

Comment: You have not defined `UNIT`. That line is not a definition.

Comment: If it is [odr-used then it must have an out of class definition as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/1708801)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23428684/1708801) is more specific to your case since you are indexing ... note that [odr violations do not require a diagnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26196095/17088010).