# constexpr array in header

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

I have the following code in a header file, that is included in 2 different cpp files:

```
constexpr int array[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
inline const int* find(int id)
{
    auto it = std::find(std::begin(array), std::end(array), id);
    return it != std::end(array) ? &*it : nullptr;
}
```

I then call `find(13)` in each of the cpp files. Will both pointers returned by `find()` point to the same address in memory?

The reason I ask is because I have similar code in my project and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I assumed both pointers would point to the same location, but I don't really have a basis for that assumption :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ standard: do namespace-scoped constexpr variables have internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107312/c-standard-do-namespace-scoped-constexpr-variables-have-internal-linkage)

Comment: @drRobertz Not always, anymore...

Comment: The question is still a duplicate (tagged c++17 and c++11), so answer the other one too ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In C++11 and C++14:**

In your example `array` has *internal linkage* (see [[basic.link]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.link#3.2)), which means it will have different addresses in different translation units.

And so it's an ODR violation to include and call `find` in different translation units (since its definition is different).

A simple solution is to declare it `extern`.

**In C++17:**

[[basic.link]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#3.2) has changed such that `constexpr` can be `inline` in which case there will be [no effect on the linkage](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.inline#footnote-94) anymore.

Which means that if you declare `array` `inline` it'll have *external linkage* and will have the same address across translation units. Of course like with any `inline`, it must have identical definition in all translation units.

Comment: @PaulSanders - it's unclear if the OP is asking about C++11 or C++17. Based on the fact that it "doesn't work" I assume C++11. But added the bit about C++17.

Comment: Well, hopefully, the OP has a choice.  Even MSVC seems to have it, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/19/c17-progress-in-vs-2017-15-5-and-15-6/).

Comment: I was compiling as C++14, but in recent Android Studio updates C++17 became available, so I changed it to 17 and it now works. Thanks for the explanation to why it didn't work and why it now works :)

Comment: Btw your link about implicit inline states that only functions and static data members are implicitly inline. In case of my array it has to be `inline constexpr`.

Comment: s/should/must/, I think!

Answer (score 3):

I can't claim to be an expert in this, but according to [this blog post](https://tech.io/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables), the code you have there should do what you want **in C++17**, because `constexpr` then implies `inline` and that page says (and I believe it):

> A variable declared inline has the same semantics as a function declared inline: it can be defined, identically, in multiple translation units, must be defined in every translation unit in which it is used, and the behavior of the program is as if there was exactly one variable.

So, two things to do:

- make sure you are compiling as C++17
- declare `array` as `constexpr inline` to force a compiler error on older compilers (and to ensure that you actually get the semantics you want - see comments below)

I believe that will do it.

Comment: I believe this change to `constexpr` is only for `static` class members, but don't quote me on that either.

Comment: @Quentin `constexpr inline int array[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };` compiles outside a class, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uEyNKsdw54AUcX4B).  I really like this new compiler feature.

Comment: I miswrote. I mean that `constexpr` variables being implicitly inline applies to class members, `constexpr` globals are still implicitly `static` AFAIK.

Comment: @Quentin Oh right, could be, I misread.  OP then please be advised to include the `inline` keyword I recommended anyway.