# Is it safe to return a static string_view created from a string literal?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, string-literals, string-view

I have a relatively simple use case: I want to associate a trait to a class which will return some user defined string, namely some user-defined registration ID. As this registrations are supposed to be defined at compile-time I would like it to be constexpr so I wrote something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct ClassRegistration
{
    static constexpr std::string_view
    Name();
};

template <>                                                                                    
struct ClassRegistration<int>                                                            
{                                                                                              
    static constexpr std::string_view                                                        
    Name()                                                                                     
    {                                                                                          
        return std::string_view{ "int" };                                                     
    }                                                                                          
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5p8xkA

Everything is working fine but as string_view doesn't actually own its buffer I wonder if it's guaranteed to be safe, that I'm not just referring to a dangling pointer. From what I read string literals are guaranteed to have the lifetime as long as that of the program itself (from this SO [Lifetime of a string literal returned by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579874/lifetime-of-a-string-literal-returned-by-a-function)).

Therefore, is this usage of string_view safe and appropriate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666043/c-standard-odr-and-constexpr-stdstring-view

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `static constexpr` variables at class scope are implicitly `inline`, so it shouldn't apply here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know, but  I understand how link could be confusing for somebody who does not know that...

Comment: Thank you @NoSenseEtAl, luckily that part was pretty clear already

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> string literals are guaranteed to have the lifetime as long as that of the program itself

That's correct.

> Therefore, is this usage of `string_view` safe and appropriate?

Yes, your code is fine.