# The set of potential results of `A::a[0]` is empty according to [basic.def.odr]/2. Why is it empty?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436665/1042389) in SO the OP says:

> Per basic.def.odr/2, the set of potential results of `A::a[0]` is
>   **empty**, so `A::a` is odr-used by this expression.

Doesn't `A::a[0]` satisfy the second bullet point in [basic.def.odr]/2? If this were the case, wouldn't `A::a` be a potential result of `A::a[0]`?

And then, we would conclude that `A::a` is not *odr-used* by `A::a[0]` in the initialization `int a = A::a[0];`, by [basic.def.odr]/3, which is exactly the opposite of what the OP said in his answer.

What am I missing?

**Edit** When I mention above the second bullet point in [basic.def.odr]/2, I'm referring to the draft N4618. This bullet point was not present in the draft N3936 referred to by the OP. So it seems to me, that according to N3936 `A::a` was odr-used by `A::a[0]`, but it is not by N4618. Am I correct?

Comment: It took me a long time to grok the odr section and I still have to think about it a lot, I have gone back to this answer many times. His comments [starting here elaborates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428684/is-a-constexpr-array-necessarily-odr-used-when-subscripted/23436665#comment35966241_23436665). My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28446388/1708801) may help a little.

Comment: For "the second bullet point", I read "If `e` is a class member access expression [...]", but "class member access" is limited to the `.` and `->` operators, neither of which you've got there. Do you mean some other bullet point? Have the items perhaps been re-ordered at some point? Otherwise I'm having trouble understanding the question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour As far as I can understand the second bullet point in [basic.def.odr]/2 says that `A::a` is potential result of `A::a[0]`.

Comment: @hvd When I say the second bullet point I'm referring to the latest draft N4618. But now I can see that N3936 doesn't have this bullet point in [basic.def.odr]/2. Sorry for this. I'll edit the question, to make it more clear.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Ah, if it was only added after that answer was written, that might already be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever drafted the list of "potential results" probably just forgot to include the one you're referring to. [Core issue 1926](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1926.html) was filed and the issue was fixed in C++17; `int a = A::a[0];` does not odr-use `A::a` (assuming the array element type is `int`). The resolution was DRed, so you can think of it as being retroactive. Evidently, it was never intended to make this odr-use `A::a` in the earlier draft (assuming the element type is `int`).

Separately, another issue was discovered with the wording, which is that it relied on the idea of an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion being performed on the object whose odr-use is in question (in this case the array `A::a`), but you can't do an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an array glvalue. This is [CWG2170](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2170.html) and it was also accepted as a DR.