# why not exist mutiple definition error when define method in class in c++?

Tags: c++, definition

I had one class with test method with body;

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(){

    }
    virtual ~Object(){

    }

    void test(){
    }
};
```

I include this `object.h` in 2 cpp files. Why is there no multiple definition error for functions `Object::test` that is available (after include) in both cpp files?

I understand that a function with complete body is a definition and not declaration, so I expect there should be multiple definition error.

is there official article talk about it?

Comment: It's because test() is [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function).

Comment: In-class function definitions are implicitly `inline`. `inline` means "may have more than one definition, as long as all definitions are identical".

Comment: Can't add anything else to Andy's statement.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (7.1.2 Function specifiers)

> 3 A function defined within a class definition is **an inline function**.
>
> 4 An inline function **shall be defined in every translation unit** in
> which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in
> every case (3.2).

And

> A function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
> odr-used if it is the unique lookup result or the selected member of a
> set of overloaded functions (3.4, 13.3, 13.4), unless it is a pure
> virtual function and its name is not explicitly qualified.

Where ODR is an abbrevation of the One Definition Rule.
Simply speaking a function is odr-used when it takes part in expressions that are evaluated.

Comment: Not clear what it is saying :( what is odr-used

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya There's an [answered question about odr-use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something) here on SO.