# constexpr of static tuple class member has linker error

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class T
{
    public:
        using Names = std::tuple<char const*, char const*>;
        static constexpr Names names {"First", "Second"};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(T::names);
}
```

As `names` is a `constexpr` I expected this to work. But I get a linker error:

The compiler:

```
> g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

The error:

```
> g++ -std=c++1y pl.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "T::names", referenced from:
      _main in pl-377031.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[[live demo]](http://ideone.com/R8F0gW)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A declaration of a `static` data member in class is never a definition<sup>1</sup>.
A definition is necessary whenever a variable is odr-used<sup>2</sup>. 
`std::get<>` takes arguments **per reference**, and binding a variable to a reference odr-uses it immediately<sup>3</sup>.

Simply define `names` outside:

```
constexpr T::Names T::names; // Edit: This goes *outside* the class "as is"!
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d5f7e403b342cbc).

---

<sup>1)</sup> [basic.def]/2:

> A declaration is a definition unless [..] it declares a `static` data
>   member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4)

<sup>2)</sup> [basic.def.odr]/4:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used  in that program; no diagnostic
>   required.

<sup>3)</sup> According to [basic.def.odr]/3:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   `ex` is odr-used by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke
>   any non-trivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of
>   the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to `e`, or `e` is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

Here the id-expression `T::names` refers to the variable in question. The only superexpression `e` that contains all the potential results of `T::names` is `T::names` itself, because the set of potential results of a function call, i.e. `std::get<0>(T::names)`, is empty. However, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is clearly not applied, and the value of `T::names` is also clearly not discarded (as it is passed to a function).
Thus it is odr-used and requires a definition.

Comment: I assume that `constexpr T::Names T::names;` must go in a compilation unit and can not be in a header file included multiple times.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye Correct - IIRC `T::names` has external linkage.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding odr-use because of the terminology involved: I've read about potentially-evaluated expressions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and potential results in the Standard and on cppreference but it's confusing. Is there a comprehensive source that explains odr-use in English?

Comment: @templateboy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something

Answer (score 2):

@Columbo posted the correct solution.

Unfortunately I am trying to build a header only library. The solution requires that the static member be compiled into one compilation unit (which is what I was using `constexpr` in the hopes of avoiding).

So I needed to stick another twist into the works to make it work. This is just to share my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
    public:
        using Names = std::tuple<char const*, char const*>;
        template<std::size_t index>
        static char const* getName()
        {
            static constexpr Names names {"First", "Second"};
            return std::get<index>(names);
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << T::getName<0>() << "\n";
}
```