# Why can [=] be used to modify member variables in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29520ad225ced72d

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    void f()
    {
        //auto f0 = []     { ++i; }; // error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

        auto f1 = [this] { ++i; };    
        auto f2 = [&]    { ++i; };
        auto f3 = [=]    { ++i; };
        f1();
        f2();
        f3();
    }

  int i = 10;  
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << "Before " << s.i << std::endl;
    s.f();
    std::cout << "After " << s.i << std::endl;
}

Before 10
After 13
```

Question: Why does `[=]` enable modification of member variables in a lambda?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Question> Why [=] enables modification of member variables in lambda?

Because (see [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)) `[=]` "captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the lambda by value and current object by reference if exists"

So `[=]` capture the current object by reference and can modify `i` (that is a member of the current object).

Comment: what the meaning of 'odr-used'?

Comment: @q0987 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something

Comment: Think of it as capturing `this` by value.

Comment: @q0987 One Definition Rule

Answer (score 9):

If you write in equivalent way, this behavior will be more clear:

```
auto f3 = [=]    { ++(this->i); };
```

You not catch `i` but `this`, it will be constant but thing that its points to will be editable as in any other pointer.

Comment: `as in any other pointer` well, not any pointer-to-`const` :P

Answer (score 6):

You can imagine that `[=]` capture `this` by value, then using the copied `this` to access `this->i`.

a copied `this` still allows you to access the object `this` points at.