# Hacking private data using c++

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

**Clarification: This question originally came from a challenge I thought of, and isn't connect with programming for real systems.**

Suppose I have a class, that I know its' architecture which I can't change, and I don't want to inherit it, but I do want to get access to its' private data and functions. How can I do it?

Suppose my class looks like this one:

```
class A {
public:
    int v = 89;

private:
    int a = 5;
    virtual void function(int a, int b) {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: The only proper answer would be to *not* do it, and instead make a sound and proper design that doesn't require hard to read, understand and maintain hacks. Especilly since hacks like that will break a number or rules (like perhaps the [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), and more) and will most likely lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It is also very implementation specific, and even changing compiler version or hardware platform may cause the hack to not work anymore.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even more likely: changing optimization levels or inlining occasions. This can work fine, then a function call gets in the way and it catches fire.

Comment: `#define private public` before including this file

Comment: @alterigel [nope, still UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901227/3233393).

Comment: Why ask a question and then answer it yourself? Also... your function "function" has a parameter 'a' which hides the private variable of the same name.

Comment: @TimRandall [Self answering is perfectly acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @TimRandall that's actually encouraged! SO is all about benefiting future researchers who encounter similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Apologies for posting my comment before it was finished (I wasn't expecting the Enter key to do that.)

Comment: @TimRandall "Also... your function "function" has a parameter 'a' which hides the private variable of the same name" - I know, my target was the idea how to access the function, so it doesn't matter for my issue.

Comment: I think that what you are trying to propose breaks the idea of data encapsulation. AFAIK there is no safe proper way of doing this without either A: modifying the original in which you stated you can not, or by using some form of interpretation that can and probably will lead to UB which is never good.

Answer (score 1):

a while ago stumbled upon a neat template trick to do this on this blog: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

Do NOT use this in any production code, it is just a educational example !!!

it takes basically leverage of the "private" being ignored on some part of template initialization

```
template<typename Tag>
struct result {
    /* export it ... */
    typedef typename Tag::type type;
    static type ptr;
};

template<typename Tag>
typename result<Tag>::type result<Tag>::ptr;

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
struct rob : result<Tag> {
    /* fill it ... */
    struct filler {
        filler() { result<Tag>::ptr = p; }
    };
    static filler filler_obj;
};

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
typename rob<Tag, p>::filler rob<Tag, p>::filler_obj;
```

usage: take following struct:

```
struct A {
private:
    void f() {
        std::cout << "proof!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

create your "robber"

```
struct Af { typedef void(A::*type)(); };
template class rob<Af, &A::f>;
```

use it:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    (a.*result<Af>::ptr)();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A less risky hack will be to make your function/class a `friend` of the class if you are allowed to modify just the header file.

```
// Add
class HackA;

class A {
public:

    // Add
    friend class HackA;

    int v = 89;

private:
    int a = 5;
    virtual void function(int a, int b) {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
};
```

Now you can use:

```
class HackA {
public:
    int number(A const& a) { return a.v; }
    int another_number(A const& a) { return a.a; }
    void target_function(A& a, int number, int another_one)
    {
       a.function(number, another_one);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    HackA hacker

    cout << hacker.number(a) << " " << hacker.another_number(a) << endl;
    hacker.target_function(a, 9, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this question is referring to a case that you can't edit the target class. If you can edit this class, just add getters and setters..

Comment: @KorelK, I didn't notice anything in your post about not being able to modify the .h file.

Comment: "Suppose I have a class, that I know its' architecture which I can't change"

Comment: @KorelK, I see. I read that very differently -- I read that to mean you can't add/remove/modify member variables or member functions.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify header file what stops anyone from adding the public definition for a getter `int getA() { return a; }` into header?

Comment: @KillzoneKid, it is less risky because you are not modifying the interface/implementation of the class.