# C++: What to recompile when an inline function in a dynamic library changes?

Tags: c++, gcc, dynamic-library, recompile, inline-functions

I have two dynamic libraries and one executable:

- libOtherLibrary.so

  - This is an existing open-source library written by someone else.
- libMyLibrary.so

  - This is my own library that depends on *libOtherLibrary.so*.
- exe

  - This is my own executable that depends on both libraries.

As a test to see when a specific function is called, I added a print statement to an **inline function** of *libOtherLibrary.so* (code details shouldn't matter):

```
template<class T>
inline void className<T>::clear() const
{
    Info << "Hello World!" << endl; // My message!
    if (isTmp() && ptr_)
    {
        if (ptr_->unique())
        {
            delete ptr_;
            ptr_ = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr_->operator--();
            ptr_ = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I then recompiled *libOtherLibrary.so*, followed by recompiling *libMyLibrary.so*. Finally I **relinked** (so no recompilation) *exe*.

The result was that any call to `className<T>::clear()` initiated in  *libMyLibrary.so* used the **old** implementation of this inline method, whereas any call to `className<T>::clear()` initiated by *libOtherLibrary*.so used the **new** implementation.

When I then decided to also recompile *exe* (followed by linking it), the result was that the **new** implementation was always used.

---

My question is: Can someone explain to me why *exe* required **recompilation, rather than relinking only**?

That is, the inlining of the function `className<T>::clear()` of *libOtherLibrary.so* should occur during the compilation stage of *libMyLibrary.so*, doesn't it? After all, it is a function contained in *libMyLibrary.so* whom calls `className<T>::clear()`. Then I'd expect that linking *exe* is sufficient, as *exe* does not call this particular inline function. The linker alone will take care of any changed ABI compatability.

Comment: First, *function-templates* are implicitly `inline`. Secondly, if there is no [ODR use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631208/1621391) of that *function-template* in any of your libraries, the compiler will not emit any new code despite your changes. Every translation unit will have a separate copy of the instantiation of your *function-template*. Hence, when you don't recompile it, the old one will still be in use. Now, having two separate and *different* copies violates ODR, but C++ doesn't require a compiler to diagnose it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: Can someone explain to me why exe **required
>   recompilation, rather than relinking only**?

Because, for your specific use-case, without it, you will inccur the wrath of [**ODR violation**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr).

---

> The result was that any call to `className<T>::clear()` initiated in 
>   *libMyLibrary.so* used the **old** implementation of this inline method, whereas any call to `className<T>::clear()` initiated by
>   *libOtherLibrary*.so used the **new** implementation.

When you have a *function-template* say:

```
template<class T>
inline void className<T>::clear(){
    ....
}
```

And it is [ODR used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631208/1621391) in multiple translation units (.cpp file). It's instantiation will be defined in each one of such translation unit because *function-templates* are implicitly `inline`.

The rules for such multiple definition are stated here [basic.def.odr/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6). And one of the listed requirements states that ***"each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens;"***.

Modifying that function template and recompiling some translation units making ODR use of it, and linking your program, without recompiling **all** the translation units making ODR-use of it violates the holy One Definition Rule of C++.

Compiler toolchains are not required to diagnose it.

Comment: Thank you. --- Just to make sure that I completely understand you: _libMyLibrary.so_ does instantiate its own function-templates for tmp. _exe_ also instantiates the function-template with the same typename `T` as _libMyLibrary.so_ does. --- So what you are saying for this case is that there will then be two definitions of `className<T>` for that specific `T`. Then, since _exe_ is executed, its definition appears first and hence its definition is used. --- However, calls made by _libOtherLibrary.so_ use the new definition. Why's that? Because className is in _libOtherLibrary.so_?

Comment: @KevinvanAs The consquences of ODR violations are unspecified. In fact, ODR violations will invoke the dreaded [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The last paragraph of the linked C++ document says *"If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined."*.

Comment: @KevinvanAs, To answer your question, UB isn't something we can explain, however, the most likely event was that all the definitions are inlined in the translation unit, and they make reference to their own copy, (Though unlikely) The linker can assume you didn't violate ODR, and mess things up in an attempt to merge the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying it:

Assuming the compiler *does* [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) (which is unrelated to `inline` keyword, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) would try hard to inline if you compile *and link* with `g++ -flto -O2` even functions which are *not* marked with `inline`), the code should be recompiled as soon as the definition of the inlined function changes. In most good C++ programs, that definition occurs in some *header* files (containing explicitly `inline` functions).

So you should recompile when header files change. Good build automation tools (e.g. `make` combined with `g++ -MD`) handle that.