# Is it legal that only declaring a function without providing its implementation if the said function would not be invoked anywhere in the project?

Tags: c++

Is it legal that only declaring a function without providing its implementation in C++ if the said function would not be invoked anywhere in the project?

Here is the [simple test](https://godbolt.org/z/8j6PcqMdG) I did. It's amazing that it compiles without any complain and works well.

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int(a)){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return a;
};

int unused(int(a));

int main()
{
    foo(1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: yes.  Nothing ever looks for the implementation so it never finds out that it's not there.

Comment: @xaxxon So, it's also legal to declare a funciton in main() without  calling it. Say `int main() {int foo_function(int(a));}` .

Comment: **Also don't write code like** `int foo(int(a))` when you can just write `int foo(int a)`

Comment: Imagine ALL the header files you include with function declarations you never use. If this was illegal C++ wouldn't work. In the end what only matters is that the linker can find matching definitions for the functions you do use. Side note `int foo(int(a))` should be written as `int foo(int a

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, **c++ allows to "declare" a function inside a function but not "define" it**. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1EPPe8hno)

Comment: According to the standard, yes.   There is no requirement that something which is declared but unused be defined.    Practically, it depends on the implementation (e.g. toolchain, specifically the linker) but most implementations either do it that way or (if it isn't the default) can be configured that way.   The main problems of having something declared but not defined comes if code is written that uses what is declared, in a way that requires there to be a definition.

Comment: @KenWhite I see. Will delete this comment after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it legal that only declaring a function without providing its implementation if the said function would not be invoked anywhere in the project?

Yes, you can omit the definition/implementation as long as that is not [ODR-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something). The **linker** needs to see the **definition** if it is odr-used. While the **compiler** can work with just the **declaration**.

In your example, this means that you *must have atmost one definition for `foo` in the entire program. But since you've not odr-used `unused`, you don't need to have its definition.*

***The "odr-use" of an entity governs when we must provide an definition for that entity.*** The rules regarding this are rather verbose and can be found at [basic.def.odr](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr)

---

> So, it's also legal to declare a funciton in main() without calling it.

Yes, we can **declare but not define** a function inside another function in c++. For example below is a contrived example:

```
int main()
{
    
    int foo_function(int a);    //valid c++
    foo_function(4);            //valid c++

    // int foo(){};                //invalid c++
   
}
```

---

##### Note

Note that here I am using "compiler" and "linker" separately to mean different things. Many informal texts use the term "compiler" to include "linker".

Comment: I would also add a simple definition of ODR-used.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Updated. Also added *"The linker needs to see the definition if it is odr-used. While the compiler can work with just the declaration."*

Comment: As a side note, you can define a function inside another function, if you wrap it into a class/struct. Doesn't work when templates come into play, but for simpler cases it works just fine.
Another option would be assigning a lambda to a variable.
In both cases, the syntax is slightly different from a normal function, but the result is the same.

Comment: @ChristianStieber As I said, c++ doesn't allow defining functions inside functions. Though there are workaround like you mentioned(lambda or wrapping into class/struct) but then those are not functions but something else completely. [Can we have functions inside functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/can-we-have-functions-inside-functions-in-c)